# How can I search for a matching substring in a file with regex and return only the substring?

Tags: grep

I have a file that is 50 MB and only one line. It is corrupt json and I am searching for a substring.

I have a problem with grep that it does not support lazy search in the default syntax. And pearl syntax doesn't seem to be supported on MacOS.

Here is a basic expression that does work but only returns the id, while I need the entire object

`grep -o  '1234' largefile`

Here are some things I tried that did not work

`grep -oP '1234.*?globalId' largefile`

> P not supported

`grep -F '1234' largefile | grep -o -E '.{30} 1234.{500}'`

> invalid repetition count(s)

`grep -o  '1234.{100}' largefile`

> doesn't return anything

How can I do this search? It doens't need to be grep. I sometimes read about `awk`, `perl`, `ripgrep` and other stuff that I have never had reason to try.

Comment: Install `pcregrep` on MacOS. It is a much better `grep` version for your OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Perl one-liner if `grep -P` is not supported. For example, this will print all matches captured in parens, 1 match per line:

```
perl -lne 'print for /(1234.*?globalId)/g' in_file
```

Comment: A follow-up question if I may: what do you think about using perl vs ripgrep for these kinds of tasks? I was able to solve the problem with both your solution and `rg -o '1234.*?global' in_file`. They seem so similar, so I don't know which tool I will want to use in the future for these kinds of tasks

Comment: @user1283776 I prefer using Perl to ripgrep because Perl is a very expressive language, where you can pack a lot into a one-liner (or almost a one-liner). You can combined multiple pattern searches and replacements into a single command. Perl comes pre-installed in macOS (usually an old version). One can install and maintain more recent Perl versions using `conda` or `perlbrew`. There is also GNU `grep`, which comes with many useful options, including `-P`. It can be installed on macOS using `homebrew`, e.g.: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193288/329079 .

Answer (score 0):

Another options is to use non match to do lazy grabbing.

The limitation of this solution is that you cannot have `G` between `1234` to `GlobalId`

For example:

```
 text="prefix 12345 some text 12345 some text 2 GlobalId more text 3 GlobalId suffix"

 echo "$text" | grep -o  "1234[^G]\+GlobalId"
 12345 some text 12345 some text 2 GlobalId

 echo "$text" | grep -oP  "1234.+?GlobalId"
 12345 some text 12345 some text 2 GlobalId
```

Read more about this trick [here](https://regular-expressions.mobi/repeat.html?wlr=1).